# need to sort sql data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

iam using sql to build report in report builder, SQL query i am using is as below

```
    select count(*) [Total Clients], li.title,
 SUBSTRING(li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title)+1)+1,2) as month1,
 CASE SUBSTRING(li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title)+1)+1,5) 
            WHEN '01' THEN 'Jan'
            WHEN '02' THEN 'Feb'
            WHEN '03' THEN 'Mar'
            WHEN '04' THEN 'Apr'
            WHEN '05' THEN 'May'
            WHEN '06' THEN 'June'
            WHEN '07' THEN 'Jul'
            WHEN '08' THEN 'Aug'
            WHEN '09' THEN 'Sep'
            WHEN '10' THEN 'Oct'
            WHEN '11' THEN 'Nov'
            WHEN '12' THEN 'Dec'
            END As [Month],
            SUBSTRING(li.title,CHARINDEX('_',li.title)+1,4),
li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name,coll.CollectionID,
SUM (CASE WHEN ucs.status=3 or ucs.status=1  then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Installed / Not Applicable',
sum( case When ucs.status=2 Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Required',
sum( case When ucs.status=0 Then 1 ELSE 0 END ) as 'Unknown',
round((CAST(SUM (CASE WHEN ucs.status=3 or ucs.status=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as float)/count(*) )*100,2) as 'Compliant%',
    round((CAST(count(case when ucs.status not in('3','1') THEN '*' end) as float)/count(*))*100,2) as 'NotCompliant%'
    From v_Update_ComplianceStatusAll UCS
inner join v_r_system sys on ucs.resourceid=sys.resourceid
inner join v_FullCollectionMembership fcm on ucs.resourceid=fcm.resourceid
inner join v_collection coll on coll.collectionid=fcm.collectionid
inner join v_AuthListInfo LI on ucs.ci_id=li.ci_id
where coll.CollectionID like '%SMS00001%' and
--title like '%SUG%' 
 Title like '%P1%' and
Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate())-1 as varchar) +  '' + '%'
--or Title like '%SUG_' + '' + CAST(year(getdate())-1 as varchar) +  '' + '%'
group by li.title,li.CI_UniqueID,coll.name,coll.CollectionID
```

data displayed from query

```
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------+
| Total Clients |           title           | month1 | Month | (No column name) |                                         CI_UniqueID                                         |         name         |  CollectionID |  Installed / Not Applicable | Required |  Unknown Compliant% | NotCompliant% |
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------+
|            30 | SUG_2017_01_P1_RFC3456    |     01 | NULL  |             2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_E586ED3A-EDD5-4145-98FB-C0B373F7E4CA | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_01-03_P1_RFC2781 |     01 | NULL  |             2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_5AEB5495-8913-4541-B29E-7D55C16E6B68 | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_03_P1_RFC2781    |     03 | NULL  |             2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_ED07143C-B357-454E-B02E-7D81AEE40869 | All Systems SMS00001 |             0 |                           0 |       30 |                   0 |           100 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_04_P1_RFC3103    |     04 | NULL  |             2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_2722FDDB-6D6B-407F-A0CE-063372571E82 | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_04-05_P1_RFC2781 |     04 | NULL  |             2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_10D742F8-FB4B-4E19-BF05-5210C790F440 | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_06_P1_RFC3123    |     06 | NULL  |             2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_3063A272-0DF9-4033-94E2-C52AF1CFD4BC | All Systems SMS00001 |            25 |                           1 |        4 |               83.33 |         16.67 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_10_P1_RFC3103    |     10 | NULL  |             2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_9C3F338B-E8BA-4AB5-8ECF-1EA8729825DA | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_11_P1_RFC3103    |     11 | NULL  |             2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_B42D69FC-2564-4542-8D5B-F5348A4080FF | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_12_P1_RFC3103    |     12 | NULL  |             2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_5C3AD217-7747-4BAC-AD06-3851014BCB94 | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------+
```

titles  shown as

```
SUG_2017_01_P1_RFC3456
SUG_2017_01-03_P1_RFC2781
SUG_2017_03_P1_RFC2781
```

i need to show only 01-03 months from these 3 rows i need on 01-03 SUG_2017_01-03_P1_RFC2781 and i need to discard jan row SUG_2017_01_P1_RFC3456 and march row means SUG_2017_03_P1_RFC2781

that applies to all rows i need

i need combine rows  and not individual rows.

new data

```
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------+
| Total Clients |           title           | month1 | Month | Year |                                         CI_UniqueID                                         |         name         |  CollectionID |  Installed / Not Applicable | Required |  Unknown Compliant% | NotCompliant% |
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------+
|            30 | SUG_2017_01_P1_RFC3456    |     01 | Jan   | 2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_E586ED3A-EDD5-4145-98FB-C0B373F7E4CA | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_01-03_P1_RFC2781 |     01 | Jan   | 2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_5AEB5495-8913-4541-B29E-7D55C16E6B68 | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_03_P1_RFC2781    |     03 | Mar   | 2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_ED07143C-B357-454E-B02E-7D81AEE40869 | All Systems SMS00001 |            11 |                          15 |        4 |               36.67 |         63.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_04_P1_RFC3103    |     04 | Apr   | 2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_2722FDDB-6D6B-407F-A0CE-063372571E82 | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_04-05_P1_RFC2781 |     04 | Apr   | 2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_10D742F8-FB4B-4E19-BF05-5210C790F440 | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_06_P1_RFC3123    |     06 | June  | 2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_3063A272-0DF9-4033-94E2-C52AF1CFD4BC | All Systems SMS00001 |            25 |                           1 |        4 |               83.33 |         16.67 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_10_P1_RFC3103    |     10 | Oct   | 2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_9C3F338B-E8BA-4AB5-8ECF-1EA8729825DA | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_11_P1_RFC3103    |     11 | Nov   | 2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_B42D69FC-2564-4542-8D5B-F5348A4080FF | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2017_12_P1_RFC3103    |     12 | Dec   | 2017 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_5C3AD217-7747-4BAC-AD06-3851014BCB94 | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2018_01_P1_RFC3103    |     01 | Jan   | 2018 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_A49E2378-BCB6-40BE-BE84-735CCFBEE43F | All Systems SMS00001 |            25 |                           1 |        4 |               83.33 |         16.67 |
|            30 | SUG_2018_02_P1_RFC3118    |     02 | Feb   | 2018 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_E6CBD108-2B1C-4C94-85F8-57174BEC34C4 | All Systems SMS00001 |            25 |                           1 |        4 |               83.33 |         16.67 |
|            30 | SUG_2018_03_P1_RFC3128    |     03 | Mar   | 2018 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_6AA69C57-9532-4ED1-BA40-1540C840BD69 | All Systems SMS00001 |            26 |                           0 |        4 |               86.67 |         13.33 |
|            30 | SUG_2018_05_P1_RFC3104    |     05 | May   | 2018 |  ScopeId_A66804AF-F55C-40D6-8AAF-82CF49CC1E5B/AuthList_D3A10469-5DE5-4998-9C59-877D3BC7225F | All Systems SMS00001 |            12 |                          14 |        4 |                  40 |            60 |
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: You have a complex query and result set which makes the description of what you are trying to solve hard to follow. Could you simplify your query/results (such as omit extraneous columns/data) to the point the ask becomes more obvious?

Comment: i need to discard jan and march if i have combine result of both of them like SUG_2017_01-03_P1_RFC2781 accept discard  SUG_2017_01_P1_RFC3456  SUG_2017_03 _P1_RFC3456 , month col is coming null as logic which i used is not working

Comment: First 3 rows
need to discard jan and mar as they are individual and take combine 01-03 of jan-mar
30  SUG_2017_01_P1_RFC3456  01  Jan 2017 -Discard
30  SUG_2017_01-03_P1_RFC2781   01  Jan 2017  - accept
30  SUG_2017_03_P1_RFC2781  03  Mar 2017- discard

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query

```
WITH commonQueryCTE AS(
  -- your query is here
),
paramQueryCTE AS(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUBSTRING(Title,5,4) Y,
    SUBSTRING(Title,10,2) M1,
    IIF(SUBSTRING(Title,12,1)='-',SUBSTRING(Title,13,2),NULL) M2
  FROM commonQueryCTE
)
SELECT *
FROM paramQueryCTE c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM paramQueryCTE p WHERE c.Y=p.Y AND c.M1 BETWEEN p.M1 AND p.M2 AND p.M2 IS NOT NULL)
   OR c.M2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c.Y,c.M1
```

SQL Fiddle Demo - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bf900/1

As variant you also can use `SELECT ... INTO #TempTable FROM ...` and after that use `#TempTable` in that query.

Comment: It is hard to verify without the data from the OP, but I like your approach to helping solve the filtering by just injecting their logic to a cte instead of asking them to clean up their code.

Comment: @David Söderlund - Thank you for kind words!